# How to get flot charts working in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, flot

So I'm trying to get flot to render a chart, and I can't seem to get it working. Here's what I have right now:

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="width:600px;height:300px">
          <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.1/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
          <div id="flot-graph"></div>
            <script>
                $(function() {
                    var myData = [[1, 2010], [2, 2543], [3, 2520], [4, 2354]];

                    $.plot($("#flot-graph"), [
                        {
                            data: myData
                        }
                    ]);

                });
            </script>
        </div>
```

Now this seems do be doing something, as it's adding the canvas do the div on the page, but it's still blank and not actually rendering anything.

```
<div id="flot-graph" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; position: relative;">
    <canvas class="flot-base" style="direction: ltr; position: absolute; left: 0px; top:  0px;">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

I've tried using the flot-rails gem, as well as adding the flot package to the vendor/assets folder (and requiring in application.js & reloading the asset pipeline), but the same thing happens and I'm going insane already.

Comment: The `<script src=...`, should be in the `<head>` of your HTML.  Other than that your code works:  http://jsfiddle.net/Efe2j/1/

Comment: I'm aware that the script is correct, which is why I'm having trouble figuring out why nothing is rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect your browser's javascript errors you'll probably see this:

`Uncaught Error: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = , height =`

You [need to specify a CSS height and width](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#introduction) on your plot `div`:

```
<div id="flot-graph" style="width:300px; height: 200px"></div>
```

Also, as I suggested in my comment in-lining a `<script src=...` in the body of HTML should be avoided.